# ionic filter by more than one condition

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, filter

I want to filter through multiple statuses.

I have the following JSON

```
[{name:'firstPerson',status:1},{name:'secondPerson',status:2},{name:'thirdPerson',status:3}]
```

And I loop through them

```
<div class="card" data-ng-repeat="res in result | filter:{ status:0, status:2} as avilableNames" >
    <div class="item item-text-wrap">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <li>{{res.name}}</li>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<ul>
    <li  ng-if="avilableNames.length===0">
        There are no available names for that status
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have tried:

- `| filter:{ status:0, status:2}`
- `| filter:{ status:0} | filter:{ status:2}`
- `| filter:{ status:[0,2]}`
- `| filter:{ status:0} || { status:2}`
- `| filter:{ status:myFilter}` which has the function below in my controller

> ```
> $scope.myFilter = function (item) 
> {
> return item = 0 || item = 2 ; 
> };
> ```

Comment: are you writing a method for a filter in your controller?

Comment: the last example that I tried was method in the controller. its the last option in the set of examples that I wrote that I tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a filter function like this; notice the `.status`:

```
$scope.myFilter = function(item){
return item.status == 0 || item.status == 2;
};
```

And in your `ng-repeat` use it like this :

```
<div ng-repeat="res in results | filter:myFilter">{{res.name}}</div>
```

Comment: Glad to help :)